# Pycharm's IPyhon console cannot display Chinese characters

Tags: pycharm, ipython

When I use the pycham console, the console is IPython, and I find that Chinese characters cannot be displayed. The information found on the Internet is to change the settings (file encoding golbal encoding) to UTF-8 or GBK. I have tried all of them, but there is no effect. How can I solve this problem?

My Pycharm and IPython version:

- PyCharm 2022.2 (Community Edition)
- IPython 8.1.0

Problems I encountered：

```
name = "黎明"
print(name)
����
```

My attempt：

My Pycharm's setting

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar, if not exactly the same issue.

I changed the encoding to UTF-8 under ***Editor->general->console***. After restarting the console it works!